# Why does installing an app take so long?

Tags: macos, applications

What exactly happens when you install an app from a .dmg image. My understanding was that it changes the inode and makes it executable (the specific application was GNU Scheme). But that can't be it since it takes about ~1m.

Comment: Are you talking about when running a .pkg installer or just mounting and dragging the app from the disk image to the /Applications folder?

Comment: I'm referring to mounting and dragging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DMG is a disk image file format.

Disk image files behave like a physical disk. In so doing, the operating system interprets them in the same way as if you had just inserted a CD-ROM, USB drive, etc into the computer.

Therefore, how long an application takes to install depends almost entirely on the application itself (e.g. It's size, whether it needs an *installer*, etc) and other factors such as the speed of your drive.

For more info on DMG files you may want to read my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252456/168832).